# How to generate multiple HTML pages using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file. How can I use this single XML file to split into multiple individual pages with each of their respective node and navigate through it with links? Can someone give me a starting point?

**XML FILE**

```
<Colors>
   <Color>
       <description>
           <p>This page is red.</p>
       </description>
   </Color>
   <Color>
       <description>
           <p>This page is blue.</p>
       </description>
   </Color>
   <Color>
       <description>
           <p>This page is green.</p>
       </description>
   </Color>
<Colors>
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    This page is red.
    </body>
</html>


<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    This page is blue.
    </body>
</html>


<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    This page is green.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to create separate output files or just multiple `<html>` tags in one big file?

Comment: Separate output files, I think. So I can navigate it through each page with a button or hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

I am afraid that in 1.0 there is no multiple output keyword - you'll have to do something externally - e.g. an XSLT with a parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html" />

  <xsl:param name="n" select="1"/>

  <xsl:template match="Color">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Colors">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Color[$n]"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and calling it repeatedly with different values for the parameter (in the example above `n` = the number of the `Color` element to use - 1, 2, 3 etc.)

In XSLT 2.0 see [this](http://www.xmlplease.com/xmltraining/xslt-by-example/examples/result-document_1.html) example

Comment: How would I go about adding a button or hyperlinks to access each individual page?

Comment: Each page will be an HTML file with some fixed name (e.g. `colorXXX.html`) - that can be used in a hyperlink. You can have the same XSLT - with a different parameter - generate this hyperlinks as well, but you still have to call it from somewhere else with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 2):

[`xsl:result-document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-result-document) can be used to output multiple processed files from a single stylesheet.