# Unique XML file, multiple HTML displays (ev. using data islands)

Tags: html, xml

I need your help with an important question for me and I would be very greatful for your opinions on this subject. The question is not so much technical, but more a reflection on the best way to proceed.

I’ve done an unique xml (a rather big one) file which contains the transcriptions of two manuscripts. Now I want to propose 3 different ways of **displaying** these transcriptions in html :

1. one transcription on the left side of the screen and the other on the right side (in order to display and highlight differences between the manuscripts)
2. only one transcription on the screen (text A)
3. only the other transcription on the screen (text B)

My questions are : can I use this unique file in order to display these 3 different modes ? I’m thinking of using « data islands » in html. And if it is possible, is that the best way to proceed ?

Or should I transform this unique file into two files (one which contains only text A and another for the text B) ? And then use data islands from these two files for the first display of the two manuscripts ?

Or is there a better way to proceed ?

For those of you who wants to have a look at my unique file, this is an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tei>
    <teiheader/>
    <text>
        <body>
            <div type="text">
                <w lemma="this" type="adv."><app><rdg wit="#A">this</rdg><rdg wit="#B">that</rdg></app>this</w>
                <w lemma="is" type="subst. fém."><app><rdg wit="#A">is</rdg><rdg wit="#B">is</rdg></app>is</w>
                <w lemma="a" type="vparpp"><app><rdg wit="#A">a</rdg><rdg wit="#B">a</rdg></app>a</w>
                <w lemma="test" type="ponfrt"><app><rdg wit="#A">test</rdg><rdg wit="#B">try</rdg></app>test</w>
            </div>
        </body>
    </text>
</tei>
```

Thank you so much for your attention and your suggestions.
Micha

Comment: Try this....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538123/how-to-generate-multiple-html-pages-using-xslt

Comment: Thank you, but this thread don't answer my question. I was asking if I can keep one single file and then use data islands or if I do best splitting the file first. The technical part of how to split is not the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better, simpler to keep on unique file, whatever you do.

You can simply hide some things or not in html by using some balises:

- style="display: none;" inside div tag
- style="visibility: hidden;" hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.
- < div hidden> in html5
- or with css

see this post: [How do you create a hidden div that doesn't create a line break or horizontal space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992114/how-do-you-create-a-hidden-div-that-doesnt-create-a-line-break-or-horizontal-sp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful suggestion and the link to the thread! I will try that and hide the <rdg> I don't want in my display :)